# supervisor keeps start and change pid

Tags: nginx, supervisord

This is mu supervisor setting

```
[program:nginx]
command=/usr/sbin/nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf -g "daemon off;"
stdout_events_enabled = true
stderr_events_enabled = true
```

And I test the result, it keeps starting and changing the pid . 
Is it normal??

```
nginx                            RUNNING   pid 11771, uptime 0:00:01
supervisor> status
nginx                            RUNNING   pid 11771, uptime 0:00:02
supervisor> status
nginx                            STARTING  
supervisor> status
nginx                            STARTING  
supervisor> status
nginx                            RUNNING   pid 11772, uptime 0:00:02
supervisor> status
nginx                            RUNNING   pid 11772, uptime 0:00:03
supervisor> status
nginx                            STARTING  
supervisor> status
nginx                            RUNNING   pid 11773, uptime 0:00:02
supervisor> status
nginx                            STARTING  
supervisor> status
nginx                            RUNNING   pid 11784, uptime 0:00:01
supervisor> status
nginx                            RUNNING   pid 11784, uptime 0:00:02
```

Comment: is there any error lines in nginx error log ?

Comment: Yes! Thank you for reminding. I check the log. It said the ip already bind . And I found a nginx process is running. I kill it and restart supervisor ,and it works!!

Answer (score 0):

I have had same problem.

First, we should put `daemon off` to nginx.conf.
Second, Check nginx process with this command `ps -ax | grep nginx` and kill the worker process and master process with `kill -9 <port_number>`.

I assume that `sudo supervisorctl stop nginx` doesn't work when nginx is already running before we manage nginx with supervisor.

Using `sudo supervisorctl status`, now I can nginx status is RUNNING.